# Storing 300 strings in an Array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am looking for suggestions. I have 300 alphanumeric strings that I need to store and a database or external file cannot be used.

The process goes like so:
When a field event triggers, the software will loop through the list of fields and if the field is found...code happens...I'm just sure of the bestest way to store the list and how to loop through it.

This is what I am using now:

```
For Each fieldID As String In FieldIDArray
            If fieldID.Equals(e.FieldID) Then
        'do stuff
            End If
Next
```

And I am populating it with:

```
Dim FieldIDArray(300) As String
    FieldIDArray(0) = "2"
    FieldIDArray(1) = "3"
    FieldIDArray(2) = "4"
...
```

Thank you!

Comment: How are you currently doing it, and what is the problem?

Comment: I updated my question but it was closed??

Comment: I'd start worrying at 30k strings. How do you plan to fill this array if there is no external storage?

Comment: What's your exact question about this?

Comment: My question is "With the parameters that I have, can't use a database or an external file, is this the optimal solution?"

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your array has 301 elements. If you wanted 300 elements then you'd use this:

```vb
Dim FieldIDArray(299) As String
```

Secondly, if you want to populate an array with literal values where you create it then don't create it and populate it separately. Do both in one go like this:

```vb
Dim FieldIDArray = {"2", "3", "4", ...}
```

When searching, there's no need for an explicit loop:

```vb
If FieldIDArray.Contains(e.FieldID) Then
    'do stuff
End If
```

You can make that comparison case-insensitive by providing an appropriate equality comparer if you want.

Comment: Thank you! I did try the .Contains but it would return the first match but not necessarily the right one. For example, if "1116" was in the list but I was looking for "16" and "1116" placement in the the list was before "16",  the return value was "1116" not "16". I'll test some more

Answer (score 0):

I would not want to type out strings "2" to "300". The following fills an array with the numbers 2 - 300. Then I change them to strings in a list. The .Range method takes (startNumber, Count) as parameters.

```
    Dim a = Enumerable.Range(2, 299)
    Dim aToString As New List(Of String)
    For Each i In a
        aToString.Add(i.ToString)
    Next
```

Then the code for finding the ID shown by jmcilhinney in his answer.